# Fermat's Last Equation

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Sorry this is an amateur question but I was wondering since Andrew Wiles solved Fermat's Last Theorem what effect does this have any impact on Geometry. Does this prove in a sense Higher Order right angle triangles? I'm just basing this on the fact that the theorem is derived from Pythagoras Theorem. (Again sorry if it sounds stupid).

Comment: I don't think so. The Pythagorean theorem in the $n$th dimension is $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = |x|$.

Comment: @thkim1011 I think you mean $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2 = |x|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Wiles, in developing his proof, through off a lot of important mathematics in the abstruse area called elliptic curves, his proof (and in fact Fermat's last theorem in the first place) has no impact on what you are thinking of as geometry.

Some mathematician might wade in and say it does make a statement about subspaces of metric spaces with $L^k$ norms for integer $k$, that are topologically equivalent to a plane.  And they would be right, but I suspect that is not the answer you are looking for!

Comment: "the abstruse area called elliptic curves"?!